# Can't access object property inside Handlebars template with Node's Express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm using the `hbs` module for Handlebars, under the Express framework:

```
var hbs = require('hbs');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', hbs.__express);
```

Setting my view var like so:

```
userModel.find({
    twitter: username
}, function(err, profile){
    if(err){
        return next(err);
    }
    res.render('profile.html', {
        profile: profile
    });
});
```

If I do this inside the template:

```
{{profile}}
```

I get:

`{ name: 'xxxxx', twitter: 'xxxxx', avatar: 'xxxxxxxx', _id: 531cd64568282e0000000001, __v: 0, links: [], booked: [] }`

however, if I do something as simple as:

`<p class="profile-name">{{profile.name}}</p>`

in the same file, there's no output!? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, this seemed to do the trick:

```
userModel.findOne({
    twitter: username
}).lean().exec(function(err, profile) {
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.lean()` and it works properly